Why Azure CDN is not listed as optional inbound service for my Web App?
I want to configure the link between Azure App Service and Azure CDN.
Both of them are ready.
Here is CDN with endpoint (I selected classic Microsoft CDN):

And here is my Web Application:

I expected to see Azure CDN among Optional Inbound Services but it is missing!
Could you please help me understand why?


Azure CDN is not listed as optional inbound service for my Web App

In requirement to configure your webapp with your Azure CDN profile but you’re not able to see Azure CDN listed as an option in the "Optional Inbound Services" of your App Service.
In general, the CDN configuration we will be available under networking blade inside webapp not under the
settings -> configuration.

and then we can see the option as below

Click on the drop down we can see the list of resources available.

Select the required front door and click on create establishment.

Refer:
Why Azure CDN is not listed as optional inbound service for my Web App? - Microsoft Q&A comment  by brtrach-MSFT
Tutorial - Add Azure Content Delivery Network to an Azure App Service web app | Microsoft Learn

Thank you for your answer. Do you know why I only have one option (Azure Front Door) and not the other one (Azure CDN)?

May be Microsoft has been promoting Front Door as a more comprehensive solution, which might lead to Azure CDN being less prominently featured or integrated in certain parts of the Azure portal. refer: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-azure-front-door-reimagined-for-modern-apps-and-content/ @walruz
